# Change UINavigationBar on the fly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

Is there a way to dynamically - on-the-fly - change style of UINavigationBar and UITabBar?

This is the way I do this right now:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
    
    init() {
        updateNavigationBarColor()
    }
    
    @StateObject var refresher = Refresher()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Tabber().environmentObject(refresher).id(refresher.shouldRefresh)
        }
    }
    
    func updateNavigationBarColor() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: ColorManager.textColorBar]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: ColorManager.textColorBar]
    }
}
```

```swift
struct Tabber: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var refresher: Refresher
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = ColorManager.textColorBar
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() { .. }
    }

}
```

```swift
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("theme") var theme = "Default Theme"
    @EnvironmentObject var refresher: Refresher
    
    let themes = ["Default Theme", "Black Blue Theme"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ColorManager.backgroundColor.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Form {
                Picker("Theme", selection: $theme) {
                    ForEach(themes, id: \.self) { theme_name in
                        Text(theme_name)
                    }
                }
                .listRowBackground(ColorManager.backgroundColor)
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }.onChange(of: theme) { newValue in
            refresher.shouldRefresh.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

I used the trick with `id` property, but even if this allows to refresh views it doesn't call the `ini()` function so the UINavigationBar or UITabBar appearance doesn't change. Also, sadly, it forces user back to the first Tab of Tabber because the whole navigation view is redrawn. But I can live with it for now.

So, when `@AppStorage("theme")` changes I would like to redraw NavigationBar and TabBar. Is this even possible? I was looking for the answer on StackOverlow, Google and Apple Developer forum and didn't find any solution.

Comment: This blog post goes into what you're doing a bit, and may have some good inspiration https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/defining-dynamic-colors-in-swift/